# How to find the next area to implant my new store?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm working on a business case, I try to find the importance of differents FEATURES to implant a new store in a new location. I try to use machine learning to find a corelation between the features.

[SHOP TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBYik.png)

I have a tables of shops with differents features (~20 columns) and my independant variable is the number of people that came to the store (AVERAGE OF VISIT PER DAY). I have only 200 lines in this tables, I think that this number  is to low to apply a ML algorithm on it.

I have a transaction table that sum up all the people that came in the different stores, I have the type of the visit (only visit, buy something). I have 800 000 lines in this table that I join with the shops table

[Transaction TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNzFS.png)

My idea is to use this table for ML because their are a lot more lines so my train set will be more important.

I apply a logisticRegression on my model to find the importance of each features

```py
model = LogisticRegression(max_iter=10000) `
# fit the model
model.fit(X, y)
# get importance
importance = model.coef_[0]
# summarize feature importance
for i,v in enumerate(importance):
 print('Feature: %0d, Score: %.5f' % (i,v))
# plot feature importance
pyplot.bar([x for x in range(len(importance))], importance)
pyplot.show()
```

But the result give me :

```
Feature: 0, Score: -0.00000
Feature: 1, Score: 0.00000
Feature: 2, Score: 0.00003
Feature: 3, Score: -0.00000
Feature: 4, Score: -0.00000
Feature: 5, Score: 0.00000
Feature: 6, Score: 0.00000
Feature: 7, Score: 0.00000
Feature: 8, Score: 0.00000
Feature: 9, Score: 0.00000
Feature: 10, Score: 0.00000
Feature: 11, Score: -0.00000
Feature: 12, Score: 0.00000
Feature: 13, Score: 0.00000
Feature: 14, Score: 0.00000
Feature: 15, Score: 0.00000
Feature: 16, Score: 0.00000
Feature: 17, Score: 0.00000
```

I think that I'm doing something wrong. I think that the algorithm doesn't understand that the lines so each contact with a visitor is linked to a store.

Before apply the logisticRegression I cleaned my data properly.

Do you think that that approach of the problem is wrong? Is it possible to find the features importances of my table in this configuration? Should I change algorithm? Do you have any clues or tips or a similar case that can help me?